# Highlighting the link that I am currently on

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i have a `background-color` for the link that I am currently in?

```
        <div id="pages">
            <a class="page" href="homepage.html">HOMEPAGE</a>|
            <a class="page" href="favorites.html">FAVORITES</a>|
            <a class="page" href="education.html">EDUCATION </a>|
            <a class="page" href="dreamplaces.html">DREAMPLACES </a>|
            <a class="page" href="dreamfoods.html">DREAMFOODS</a>
        </div>
```

This is how my output looks, but I would like it to be highlighted when I am on that link

[image]

Comment: you can get the url, split it to get the specific page reference, compare that to the hrefs of your links and apply an active class. A much easier approach is to use php, create the navigation as a list, set the active page above the list and then using php echo the active class into the li's of the list. Both options allow you to set an "active" class that you can then style accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to how you could highlight a link based on that page you are suppose to be on then you could simply give is a class like this:

```
<a class="page current" href="homepage.html">HOMEPAGE</a>|

.current {
  background-color: red;
}
```

You would simply change which `a` has the `current` class for each page.

Comment: nice - but a typo - "bacbkground-color" should be "background-color"

Comment: @shiya sheenaz - just note that after two of your links - you have a space but not in all of them - this will lead to slightly different spacing in your final menu. They should all have them - or none have them. Just a thought.  :) And this works because you manually add the current class into the link that is related to the page - all other links do not have that class on that page and so when you click a link to another page - that will have the current class only in that link and so each page will have a currnt class based on the page you are on. This class allows the styling of that link.

Comment: funny thing thou i am unable to change the color to any other color :'(

Comment: @shiyasheenaz To change the color just replace `red` with a hexcode or rgb value. One example might be `background-color: #FF0000;`

Comment: i do no how to add coors but it doesnt work i have even tried using hex  `.current {
 background-color:#D4D409;
}`

Comment: You might have conflicting CSS. try adding `!important` to the end to see if the changes go through. If they do when you add that then that means there is some CSS that is overwriting `.current` you could choose to keep the `!important` there or rearrange your CSS. `background-color: #D4D409 !important;`

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.selected { background-color: #eee;}  //the color is just for demonstration
```

Javascript:

```
$('a[href="' + document.location.href.split('/').pop() +  '"]').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: This might cause issues since he is using relative paths in his `href`s. `document.location.href` returns the whole url.

Comment: @KyleMessner `document.location.href` returns the absolute path even if the `href` tag is a relative path

Comment: right so if the `a` tag's `href` value == `somepage.html` then the jquery selector wont find it because it would be looking for an `a` tag with an `href` that is something like `www.somewebsite.com/somepage.html`.

Comment: @KyleMessner you are right. I edited my answer. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can either compare the current link to your href or you can put unique classes on you link that same on href then get the path of the url and add some class on it.

Comment: with respect - this solution was posted some time ago (in comparing the url and hrefs) and adding a class based on that comparison. Best to read the preceding answers / comments so as to avoid doubling up.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a background color to a Link is a simple task, but can be complicated based on how you're implementing your navigation menu.  Are you copy/pasting the code above onto each HTML document, or are you doing this a fancy way?

IF you are copy pasting:
simply add an additional class to the current page's navigation menu like below:

```
<div id="pages">
    <a class="page currentPage" href="homepage.html">HOMEPAGE</a>|
    <a class="page" href="favorites.html">FAVORITES</a>|
    <a class="page" href="education.html">EDUCATION </a>|
    <a class="page" href="dreamplaces.html">DREAMPLACES </a>|
    <a class="page" href="dreamfoods.html">DREAMFOODS</a>
</div>
```

In your CSS document you would assign the "currentPage" class a background Like below:

```
.currentPage { 
    background-color:green;
}
```

---

HOWEVER, if you are using one navigation document and including it in each of your pages via a script, then the most strait forward answer would be to add a variable to the classes so you can control that variable on your child page.
For Example: (Using PHP as an example, if this is your method but not your language please tell us what your server side language is so we can give you an example with said language)

```
<div id="pages">
    <a class="page <?php echo $homePage ?>" href="homepage.html">HOMEPAGE</a>|
    <a class="page <?php echo $favPage ?>" href="favorites.html">FAVORITES</a>|
    <a class="page <?php echo $eduPage?>" href="education.html">EDUCATION </a>|
    <a class="page <?php echo $DPlacesPage?>" href="dreamplaces.html">DREAMPLACES </a>|
    <a class="page <?php echo $DFoodPage?>" href="dreamfoods.html">DREAMFOODS</a>
</div>
```

and on your individual web pages you would declare the appropriate variable so it is not null.  for example, on the Education page, you would declare

```
<?php $eduPage = ' currentPage'?>
```

and that would echo out your "currentPage" class to your Education Link. I am sure there are more effective ways to do this, but if you are using server side processing and are not using any other logic to generate your Navigation menu, then this will get the job done... 
Your CSS page would need to have the following in it for this to work as well:

```
.currentPage { 
    background-color:green;
}
```